# Microbit - Control an LED that is powered externally

Tags: power, led, usb, brightness, microbit

I am trying to make a motion activated light with my Microbit. I have a 1W superbright LED and its clear the Microbit won't supply the current needed for this LED. So I'm using a 5V USB micro-B with a LD1117 for 5v:3V and a resistor to power the LED which works fantastically and is more than bright enough. My question is how can I use the microbit to control the LED? I want the brightness of the USB power but the control of the Microbit.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Tyris and welcome!

If I understood right, you just want simply on/off connection to your led controlled by micro:bit.

You need to use transistor or mosfet etc etc, which will work as a driver and handle higher currents which led requires.

You can use use p-channel mosfet for example. This kind of Mosfet is little bit overkill here, but great to understand concept.

**Here is source to understand what you are trying to accomplish:**

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html

Attach your led as in image and calculate needed resistor.

**some help from here to understand current limiting**

https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/219)

Those are just first links which appeared from google but there is tons of articles about this subject if those are not enough which I provided here.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! I guess I wasn't googling correctly... Thank you!